# JS/jQuery hiccup with bootstrap carousel/setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on a browser game, and ran into a few problems.
I have incorporated a bootstrap carousel within a bootstrap modal.

From there, i read a variable called `data-interval` on each slide, to get a custom interval, using a pause command. (found here on stackoverflow as well)

When my text is displayed, an audio file is almost played.

It all almost works, except the custom interval code, is messing up.
It seems to me, it's adding the remaining seconds.
So the slide is open longer and longer.

The last problem, is that when the modal/carousel closes, the audio files restarts after some time, and I'm guessing the carousel keeps running, even it's not displayed on the screen.

So.. cooked down:
1. setTimeout (time between slides) is messed up.
2. Audio/carousel keeps running after closure.

Here is the [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Supremacy2k/tpzf2wxk/4/)

The code in question:

```js
$(function () {
    var t;

    /* Starting the timer, for slider interval */
    /* Getting desired interval from 'data-interval' */
    var start = $('#myCarousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
    t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000});", start - 1000);

    /* Getting Total Number of slides */
    var totalItems = $('.item').length;
    var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
    $('#carIndex').html(currentIndex + " / " + totalItems + " / 13000 / 20th_century.wav");

    /* Setting the standard slide interval */
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: start
    });

    /* Show modal with slide */
    $('.modal').modal('show');

    /* Play first audio, on first slide */
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.src = 'http://s2k.chronoslegacy.com/lyd/20th_century.wav';
    audio.play();

    /* Carousel Starting! */
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {

        /* Clear current setTimeout() */
        clearTimeout(t);
        /* Getting desired interval */
        var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');

        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
        /* Setting new slide interval */
        t = setTimeout("$('#myCarousel').carousel();", duration - 1000);

        /* Getting current slide number */
        currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

        /* Selecting audio file depending on slide number */
        switch (currentIndex) {
            case 1:
                sound_file = '20th_century';
                /*playSound(this, sound_file);*/
                break;
            case 2:
                sound_file = '2048';
                break;
            case 3:
                sound_file = '2057';
                /* playSound(this, sound_file); */
                break;
            case 4:
                sound_file = '21th_century';
                /* playSound(this, sound_file); */
                break;
            case 5:
                sound_file = '2109';
                /* playSound(this, sound_file); */
                break;
            case 6:
                sound_file = '2109_2502';
                /* playSound(this, sound_file); */
                break;
            default:
                sound_file = 'none';
                break;
        }

        /* Debug readout! */
        $('#carIndex').html(currentIndex + " / " + totalItems + " / " + duration + " / " + sound_file);

        audio.src = 'http://s2k.chronoslegacy.com/lyd/' + sound_file + '.wav';
        audio.play();

        /* If slide has reached it's end, wait for desired interval, and close it */
        if ($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('.carousel').each(function () {
                    $(this).carousel({
                        interval: false
                    });
                });
            }, duration);
        }

        /* Making the carousel slide */
        if ($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: That the code reads the number from `data-interval` and sets the timeout, so it slides according to the number of secs from `data-interval`.  Also it's supposed to stop the carousel when it closes, and not playing any more sounds from the modal.

Comment: This issue is still open and unresolved.

Comment: Issue is no longer relevant.
Rebuild the script, in a different way.